# PHP mail function doesn't encode french letters for mail subject

Tags: php, email, header, encode

So, the encoding for the content of the e-mail work, but the encoding for the subject doesn't. I have tried different types of encoding, but they don't seem to work.. Please help me out here.

So what I get in my inbox is "ÂšÂšuūūuķ&#31" as the subject, and everything works as it should in the content of the e-mail.

```
$subject = $_POST['sub'];

$headers = "From: $name <$from>\nReply-To:$from\nReturn-Path:$from\nX-Mailer: PHP\n";
$limite = "_parties_".md5 (uniqid (rand()));
$headers .= "Date: ".date("l j F Y, G:i")."\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"."\n";
$headers .= " boundary=\"----=$limite\"\n\n";

$message = '<html><body><table>';
$message .= '<tr>';
$message .= '<td colspan=2>'.$email_message.'</td>';
$message .= '</tr>';
$message .= '<tr>';
$message .= '<td height=10 colspan=2>'.$irack_id.'</td>';
$message .= '</tr>';
$message .= '</table>';
$message .= '</body>';
$message .= '</html>';

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Comment: What are you sending into `$subject`?

Comment: I'm sending different French letters.

Answer (score 2):

You need to encode the French Characters. Try this:

```
$subject = utf8_encode($_POST['sub']);
```

Or encode the headers

```
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";
```

Comment: Yeah, I already tried this before. All I get when I receive the e-mail is "������������������������ù ����������ë".
What I sent was "ùûüÿàâæçéèêëùûüÿàâæçéèêëùûüÿàâæçéèêë"

Comment: It would have helped if you had mentioned that in your question ;)

Comment: ����������������� any new updates about this output ?

Answer (score 0):

https://ncona.com/2011/06/using-utf-8-characters-on-an-e-mail-subject/

```
$to = 'example@example.com';
$subject = 'Subject with non ASCII ó¿¡á';
$message = 'Message with non ASCII ó¿¡á';
$headers = 'From: example@example.com'."\r\n"
.'Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8'."\r\n";
mail($to, '=?utf-8?B?'.base64_encode($subject).'?=', $message, $headers);
```